# CSS translate X causes white space on right side of screen mobile

Tags: html, css, reactjs, safari

I am using css translate to create a sidebar for my site. The problem is that after clicking the side bar, and collapsing it. It creates white space on the right hand side of the screen. This only happens on mobile devices.

This project is written on React JS so no jquery fixes.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me!

```
body, html {
  overflow-x: hidden; 
}
```

Comment: But it doesn't in this case. Try it yourself, bring up the inspector and add overflow-x: hidden; to body and html and you'll see it still happens.

Answer (score 0):

*Edit:* This seems to fix it for me:

```
html, body {
    width: 100vw;
    overflow-x: hidden;
}
```

Comment: Hi there. I tried your solution, I deleted the whole element and tried opening the menu again and same happend. The thing is, that element isn't even rendered as long as you don't click to the cart page. So this is happening even when that container does not exist in the document.

Comment: @ThomasCharlesworth Gotcha. I've updated my answer, which seems to work on testing.

Comment: This solution fixes one problem but creates another issue. With this CSS fix, it stops your whole document from being able to listen to scrollEvents. If you noticed, I had the header bar sticky when you scrolled down. With this CSS attached to HTML and BODY. document.body.addEventListener('scroll' or document.scrollingElement.addEventListener('scroll' will no longer trigger.

Comment: Hmm strange, as the solution above doesn't seem to stop your sticky scroll behaviour for me? But after more tests my solution above doesn't seem to work anyway. It looks like when you scroll to the point where the sticky behaviour kicks in, then it resets the window width and the extra space disappears. Seems like a bug, where the `body` or `html` isn't re-rendering after the sidebar transitions finish.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution that involves using media queries for the classes that have a translateX, like so:

```
 `@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
    .classWithTranslateX {
      -webkit-transform: translateX(10px);
      transform: translateX(10px);
  }
}`
```